# Issue with Entity Framework Performance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am working on a C# ASP.NET MVC application that uses Entity Framework 6 (code first). We have a model that has multiple child objects, including one that inherits from a base class. There is a web page that generates a view from this model (after mapping it to a view model). The data is fetched via a call like this:

```
_context.TableName.Include(includes..).FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id);
```

There are multiple calls to `.Include`. Due to the complexity of the model Entity Framework generates a large query.

The first time the code runs, it takes about 4.5 to 5 seconds. Subsequent views of the page result in the data access logic running in around 450 to 550 milliseconds (using the Stopwatch class to profile).

However if I add a loop to repeatedly pull back the exact same data after the initial fetch each call takes around 12 to 15 milliseconds.

I thought this was simply because these calls were obviously returning the object from Entity Framework's cache. That is, no call to the database or materialization required. So I added logic to dispose of the context between each iteration of the loop, with a new context being created each time.

Running this under SQL Profiler showed a torrent of calls to the database from Entity Framework. However the result was the same.

This makes me think there some opportunity to optimize performance that we are missing. Does anyone have any idea as to why there is this discrepancy between how long the data access logic takes to run when the web page is viewed, and when that exact same logic is run (from within the same web page call) in a loop?

Does creating a new context not completely 'reset' Entity Framework? There must be some caching or something else going on to explain the massive performance difference.

Huge thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, first request is long because of initiating a db connection. Next request a served faster, even if you dispose and recreate dbcontext, because underlying db connection are still remain in connections pool of your app domain. Same requests in a loop a served super fast, because of caching (on both sides, EF and SQL server).

Comment: I was wondering do you need each and every child object loaded initially at once. If not, you should consider lazy loading instead of eager.

Comment: Most likely, this is because the backend database is caching the data. In the case of SQL Server, on the very first read, all the necessary data pages have to be loaded from disk into the buffer pool and this takes its time. Once that's done, however, queries are being answered by providing data from the in-memory buffer pool. This buffer pool is **not** reset when the EF context is disposed of - this buffer pool will stick around.

Comment: Try sending pure parameterized SQL instead.  EF supports strong binding of raw SQL For time like tis.

Comment: Have seen this in EF 6 and from experience was nothing to do with establishing the DB connection.  It was EF generating the query that takes time and then SQL Server generating it's own query plan (proved by debugging and profiling).  EF caches the query and Sql Server caches the query plan so execution is much faster in subsequent calls.  As described in your question it happened with complex data models e.g. inheritance from abstract base types.  Performance was so bad for some queries (> 1min) we had to write raw SQL queries or we simply bypassed EF and used Dapper.

Comment: @JohnPeters I haven't tried using parameterized SQL, will look into that, cheers.

Comment: @Brad I have been looking at Dapper for the last couple of weeks, it appears to be at least an order of magnitude faster with complex queries like this. Your recommendation is definitely a good one.